# Rotation with Geometry Nodes part 2

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am designing some kind of crane. It can rotate globally, rotate through the arm and expand it.

What I need now, is that the head of the crane, where the hook connects, always points in the direction of the ground.

[image]

How can I rotate the "Arm 4" object so that it always has the same angle with respect to the ground?

[image]

The object to rotate 'Arm4'

[image]

My Geometry Nodes.
Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easy. I just had to rotate the "Arm4" object in the opposite direction before moving it.

[image]

The new Geometry Node

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 nice !!!!!!!